# RExcel in 2016 not working

Tags: r, rexcel

I usually work with RExcel and had no problems with it until today that I tried running some code. I tried the same code on December 30th and it worked perfectly but today I got the "There seems to be no R process connected to Excel" error. I already reinstalled all the components to see if it was an outdated version of RExcel (which was the problem last time this message appeared constantly) but I still haven´t solved it. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put you out of your misery, it seems it is a problem with the license embedded in the statconn program/installer. The mailing list suggest a new version will be out in a few days. It failed on me suddenly too!

Cheers Iain

On Thu, Dec 31, 2015 at 5:03 PM, Thomas Baier wrote:

Hi Philipp & Kunal,

this seems to be a problem with statconnDCOM for the Home&Student Version. Will upload a fix within the next days.

Sorry for the inconveniences.

Best regards, Thomas

Am 31.12.2015 um 09:37 schrieb Philipp Guggenberger:

Hello Kunal,

same problem here. It seems, that the statconn license has been expired. But on the statconn website is no newer license file to download. If you set the date of your PC back to e.g. 12/30 the add-in works fine.

Regards

Philipp

Rcom-l mailing list Rcom-l at lists.univie.ac.at https://lists.univie.ac.at/mailman/listinfo/rcom-l
-- Thomas Baier http://www.statconn.com/

Comment: Thank you so much! I will keep an eye out for the new version.